# SQL Innerjoin problem on more than 1 Table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

i have this table :

Customers    : CustomerID|CustomerName|ContactName|Address|City|PostalCode|Country

Orders       :  OrderID|CustomerID|EmployeeID|OrderDate|ShipperID

OrderDetails : OrderDetailID |  OrderID | ProductID | Quantity

Products     : ProductID|ProductName|SupplierID|CategoryID|Unit | Price

Categories   : CategoryID|CategoryName|Description

OrderDetails : OrderDetailID |  OrderID | ProductID | Quantity

and i want to show

CustomerName|OrderDate|CategoryName|ProductName|Quantity|Price

Anyone can help me, plz?

Comment: No. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: One link may help you is [using inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

It may help you,

```
select cu.CustomerName, odr.OrderDate, ct.CategoryName, pr.ProductName, od.Quantity, 
pr.Price from Customers cu 
inner join Orders odr on cu.CustomerID = odr.CustomerID
inner join OrderDetails od on odr.OrderID = od.OrderID
inner join Products pr on pr.ProductID = od.ProductID
inner join Categories ct on ct.CategoryID = pr.CategoryID
```